# Using Get-ADUser with Import-Csv for future expansion to update user using Set-ADUser

Tags: windows, powershell, csv

At the end of this project, I am trying to use a CSV file to update users personal details within AD. I plan to use Get-ADUser piped into Set-ADUser

My current problem is returning the user records from AD using Get-ADUser

My CSV file is as follows

```
FirstName,LastName,DisplayName,CompanyName,EmailAddress
John,Doe,John Doe,Test Company,john.doe@company.com
Jane,Doe,Jane Doe,Test Company,jane.doe@company.com
```

My PowerShell script looks like this

```
Import-Csv .\Users.csv | ForEach {

Write-Host $_.EmailAddress
Write-Host $_.DisplayName

"`"$($_.EmailAddress)`""

Get-ADUser -Filter { userPrincipalName -eq "`"$($_.EmailAddress)`""}
}
```

What is returned is

```
john.doe@company.com
John Doe
"john.doe@company.com"
jane.doe@company.com
Jane Doe
"jane.doe@company.com"
```

Running Get-ADUser without using variables like below, returns the user account as it should, whereas the above code does not.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter { userPrincipalName -eq "john.doe@company.com"}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The $_ is a variable for the current value in the pipe line or current object that the cmd-let returns. When you use $_ in Get-ADUser, it $_ will be the object returned from Get-ADUser cmd-let. Just create a variable and assign $_.EmailAddress inside foreach loop and pass this variable to filter.

```
Import-Csv .\Users.csv | ForEach {
    $emailAddress = $_.EmailAddress
    Write-Host $_.EmailAddress
    Write-Host $_.DisplayName
    Get-ADUser -Filter { userPrincipalName -eq $emailAddress }
}
```

Comment: I did actually try that at one stage. I tried it again, but Get-ADUser still doesn't return any results.

Comment: What happens then if you do this: Import-Csv .\Users.csv | ForEach {
    $emailAddress = $_.EmailAddress
    Write-Host $_.EmailAddress
    Write-Host $_.DisplayName
    Get-ADUser | where-Object { $_.userPrincipalName -eq $emailAddress }
}